# android position:absolute, overflow-y:scroll and -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch very choppy

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I am using an absolutely positioned element, with height equal to height size, with overflow-y:scroll and -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch but on android the animation is really REALLY choppy.

I read somewhere that this to be working properly needs the z-index to be 0, but since this element is on top of another one I definately need it to be a positive one. (let alone I tried it and I still get choppy results).

I finally found a solution to the problem I've wasted about 10 days on and this is the only drawback. Hopefully someone also encountered this and has a solution!

Any help on this one? :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is awkward. During all the testing I had used:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

in order to fix other problems and looks like this was the culprit. I just spent a couple of hours debugging to find this. Oh, well, I hope noone does the same mistake, but in case you do, here is the answer! :P

Comment: +1: Thanks for taking the time to post your solution!

Comment: Not directly, but as someone who has to deal with this kind of thing I'm always happy to know there are solutions out here waiting to be found.  :-)